# ng-Map not showing text in info-window

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

I have the following Code:

```
<ng-map>
        <marker ng-repeat="item in items" position="{{item[4]}},{{item[5]}}" name="{{item[1]}}" on-click="showInfoWindow('myInfoWindow')">
          <info-window id="myInfoWindow">
              <h4>{{this.name}}</h4>
          </info-window>
        </marker>
</ng-map>
```

The Problem is that I see the info-window but the text inside `h4` is empty and not the content of `{{item[1]}}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`info-window` directive must not be used with `ng-repeat`, the following example shows how to initialize a single instance of info window for markers:

```js
angular.module('ngMap').controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,NgMap) {
  
  NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
    $scope.map = map;
  });
  $scope.cities = [
    {id: 1,name: 'Oslo', pos:[59.923043, 10.752839]},
    {id: 2,name: 'Stockholm',pos:[59.339025, 18.065818]},
    {id: 3,name: 'Copenhagen',pos:[55.675507, 12.574227]},
    {id: 4,name: 'Berlin',pos:[52.521248, 13.399038]},
    {id: 5,name: 'Paris',pos:[48.856127, 2.346525]}
  ];
  $scope.showCity = function(event, city) {
    $scope.selectedCity = city;
    $scope.map.showInfoWindow('myInfoWindow', this);
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>

<div ng-app="ngMap" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <ng-map default-style="true" zoom="5" center="59.339025, 18.065818">

    <info-window id="myInfoWindow" >
      <div ng-non-bindable>
        <h4>{{selectedCity.name}}</h4>
      </div> 
    </info-window>

    <marker ng-repeat="c in cities" 
      position="{{c.pos}}" title="{{c.name}}"  id="{{c.id}}"  on-click="showCity(event, c)">
    </marker>

  </ng-map>

</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/krzf2mqo/)

Comment: hi getting error `$scope.map.showInfoWindow is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<ng-map>
    <span ng-init="name='Test123'">
        <marker ng-repeat="item in items" position="{{item[4]}},{{item[5]}}" name="name" on-click="showInfoWindow('myInfoWindow')"></marker>
        <info-window id="myInfoWindow">
            <h4>{{name}}</h4>
        </info-window>
    </span>
</ng-map>
```

Comment: And what if name would not be Test123 but item[1]?

Comment: @gurehbgui Let me make one thing clear. info-window is not enclosed in marker tag. So you don't expect a separate window for each marker.

Comment: Even if I enclose it it's not working (changed the question)